# RStudio Server vs opencpu.org for web based GUI of own package?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server, opencpu

Being a RStudio user since its earlier days I just installed RStudio Server on my local ubuntu VM. The browser version acts quick, offers user management etc. – a lot of reasons for me to be impressed here. I also like the fact that integrating it with an LDAP based user management does not seem to be a long shot.

Besides I have been following the development of [opencpu.org](http://www.opencpu.org) and Jeroen Ooms' other projects for quite some time. Applications like the [lme4](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~jeroen/lme4.html) are relevant for me in particular.

I am developing an institution specific R package for our institute on my own and want to increase its usage within the organization by putting in on an application server and by adding a web based gui.

Both projects described above offer way more than I need, so no need to re-invent to wheel. 
But I am not sure which kind of wheel I should use here.

Which architecture would you use to built a web-based GUI with LDAP user-management (using an external LDAP server) for a custom package?

Answer (score 6):

RStudio server is more so about offering R sessions to users. For an abstracted GUI you just want a RESTful connection to R so go with opencpu.org

Comment: I thought about modifying R Studio Server as an alternative to that, cause it seems to offer a nice user management.

Comment: That would most likely be a very sizable task, I recommend going with Twitter Bootstrap + opencpu.org for a quick and easy MVP.